# MS Access Linked Tables To SQL Server 2019 ODBC Error

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access-2016, linked-tables

I have migrated MS Access 2016 tables to SQL Server 2019 database, and I have made tables as linked tables with Windows authentication. So, the front end is MS Access and the back end is MS SQL Server. Everything works fine until I want to give permissions read only to some domain users, but the connection will fail and I can't connect to the tables.

The only solution I have found is give all users ownership of the database that they can link the table.

The question is: Is there anyway to give read only permission to a specific user on the domain and keep the ODBC connection valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your DSN connects to SQL Server using a specific login.  You would need to switch the DSN to use windows authentication so that each users credentials are used.  Doing this would authenticate against the SQL Server database using their domain account which honors the SQL Server db permissions.

This does have the caveat that you'd also need to create logins on the SQL Server for each user.

Comment: Hi Squillman, many thanks for your reply to my question. I am using windows authentication for my users on the database. Yes, you are right, I have created login then a user on the login, and I have granted select permissions to some tables not all, but when I have used the MS Access to check if I can only view some linked tables, I was shocked that I can access all linked tables? Do you have any idea why this is happening?